# Why do image host URLs need to be allowed explicitly in next.config before we can load them through next/Image?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

If we want to load an image using Next.js' Image component, we first have to allow that URL in the `next.config.js` file, either through the `domains` field or the the `remotePattern` field:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**.example.com',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I couldn't find a proper explanation anywhere **why this is the case**. What exactly could a bad actor do if all domains were allowed to be loaded into our `next/Image`s?
And is it secure to allow image hosts that are shared with others, e.g. `unsplash.com`?